# UIView multiple animations with different durations

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a background UIImageView which is constantly animating with this code that gets called at the end of ViewDidAppear:

```
- (void)beginBackgroundAnimation
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:45
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^{
                     _background.frame = CGRectMake(-_background.frame.size.width + self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                    _background.frame.origin.y,
                                                    _background.frame.size.width,
                                                    _background.frame.size.height);
                 }
                 completion:nil];
}
```

The problem is, when I perform another animation, such as this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:delay animations:^{
            registerRowView.alpha = 1;
            registerRowView.frame = newFrame; // this line kills the animation
        }];
```

The background animation resets to it's original state and stops animating..

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can do the second animation in completion block of first animation

Comment: The second animation is fired through a triggered action by the user, so completion block wouldn't work :(

Comment: Did you try adding the `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` option to second animation?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Keep a bool variable globally like: `BOOL isFirstAnimationCompleted;` and set it `false` in the starting of the first animation.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:45
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                     animations:^{
                         _background.frame = CGRectMake(_background.frame.size.width + self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                        _background.frame.origin.y,
                                                        _background.frame.size.width,
                                                        _background.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                           if(finished) {
                               isFirstAnimationCompleted = finished;                           
                           }

                         }];
```

Check while the user wants to perform the second animation like:

```
if(isFirstAnimationCompleted) {
   [UIView animateWithDuration:delay animations:^{
            registerRowView.alpha = 1;
            registerRowView.frame = newFrame; // this line kills the animation
        }];
}
```

Comment: The second animation is fired through a triggered action by the user, so it happens independent of the background animation

Comment: one more thing: in this code `CGRectMake(-_background.frame.size.width + self.view.frame.size.width, _background.frame.origin.y, _background.frame.size.width, _background.frame.size.height);` 
The `-` you added for `_background.frame.size.width` is correct? The animation can't played by using that.